# Unit Testing for JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, junit, jmenuitem, actionevent

I am new to JUnit testing. I am trying to test a method that exports a report. Basically, this method pops up a save menu to select where to save the file at and also gets the report from another class. I am not sure what I need to test here or how to even test it. I have added my JMenuItem and my actionEvent as well. Any ideas or help would be greatly accepted.

Here is my JMenuItem:

```
    JMenuItem jMenuFileexportProjectReport = new JMenuItem(exportProjectReportAction);
```

Here is my Action event for the JMenuItem:

```
        public Action exportProjectReportAction =
            new AbstractAction(Local.getString("Export Project Report")) {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                reportExportAction(e);
            }
    };
```

Here is my method to export the report:

```
public void reportExportAction(ActionEvent e) {

            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            chooser.setFileHidingEnabled(false);
            chooser.setDialogTitle(Local.getString("Export Project Report"));
            chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
            chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(
                    new AllFilesFilter(AllFilesFilter.XHTML));
            chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new AllFilesFilter(AllFilesFilter.HTML));

            String lastSel = (String) Context.get("LAST_SELECTED_EXPORT_FILE");
            if (lastSel != null) {
                    chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(lastSel));
            }

            ProjectExportDialog dlg =
                    new ProjectExportDialog(
                            App.getFrame(),
                            Local.getString("Export Project Report"),
                            chooser);

            String enc = (String) Context.get("EXPORT_FILE_ENCODING");
            if (enc != null) {
                    dlg.encCB.setSelectedItem(enc);
            }



            Dimension dlgSize = new Dimension(550, 500);
            dlg.setSize(dlgSize);
            Dimension frmSize = App.getFrame().getSize();
            Point loc = App.getFrame().getLocation();
            dlg.setLocation(
                    (frmSize.width - dlgSize.width) / 2 + loc.x,
                    (frmSize.height - dlgSize.height) / 2 + loc.y);
            dlg.setVisible(true);

            if (dlg.CANCELLED) {
                    return;
            }

                    Context.put(
                            "LAST_SELECTED_EXPORT_FILE",
                            chooser.getSelectedFile().getPath());

            int ei = dlg.encCB.getSelectedIndex();
            enc = null;
            if (ei == 1) {
                    enc = "UTF-8";
            }
            boolean nument = (ei == 2);
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            boolean xhtml =
                    chooser.getFileFilter().getDescription().indexOf("XHTML") > -1;
             CurrentProject.save();
             ReportExporter.export(CurrentProject.get(), chooser.getSelectedFile(), enc, xhtml, 
                              nument); 
            }
```

Class the creates a HTML report:

```
public class ReportExporter {

static boolean _chunked = false;
static boolean _num = false;
static boolean _xhtml = false;
static boolean _copyImages = false;
static File output = null;
static String _charset = null;
static boolean _titlesAsHeaders = false;
static boolean _navigation = false;

static String charsetString = "\n";




public static void export(Project prj, File f, String charset, boolean xhtml, boolean chunked) {


    _chunked = chunked;
    _charset = charset;
    _xhtml = xhtml;

    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        output = new File(f.getPath() + "/Project Report.html");
    }
    else {
        output = f;
    }

    NoteList nl = CurrentStorage.get().openNoteList(prj);
    Vector notes = (Vector) nl.getAllNotes(); 



   //Creates Labels for the HTML output for each section.
   String notesLabelHTML = "Notes";
   String tasksLabelHTML = "Tasks";
   String eventsLabHTML = "Events";


    //NotesVectorSorter.sort(notes);
    Collections.sort(notes);



    Writer fw;

    if (output.getName().indexOf(".htm") == -1) {
        String dir = output.getPath();
        String ext = ".html";

        String nfile = dir + ext;

        output = new File(nfile);
    }        
    try {
        if (charset != null) {
            fw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output),
                    charset);
            charsetString = "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset="
                    + charset + "\" />";
        }
        else
            fw = new FileWriter(output);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        new ExceptionDialog(ex, "Failed to write to " + output, "");
        return;
    }

    //Writes the title and the notes section of the HTMl Report
    write(fw, "<html>\n<head>\n" + charsetString + "<title>"
            + prj.getTitle()
            + "</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1 class=\"projecttitle\">" 
            + prj.getTitle() +  "</h1>\n" +"\n<br>\n" 
            + "</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2 class=\"projecttitle\">"
            + notesLabelHTML + "</h2>\n" );
    generateChunks(fw, notes);

    //Writes the Task section of the HTML Report
    write(fw, "\n<hr></hr><a" +"</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2 class=\"projecttitle\">" + "\n<br>\n"
            + tasksLabelHTML + "</h2>\n" );

    //writes the Events section of the HTML Report
    write(fw, "\n<hr></hr><a" +"</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h2 class=\"projecttitle\">" + "\n<br>\n"
            + eventsLabHTML + "</h2>\n" );

    //Writes the ending of the report with the data and time
    write(fw, "\n<hr></hr><a "
            + "\n<br></br>\n" + new Date().toString()
            + "\n</body>\n</html>");
    try {
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        new ExceptionDialog(ex, "Failed to write to " + output, "");
    }
}




public static String getNoteHTML(Note note) {
    String text = "";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    AltHTMLWriter writer = new AltHTMLWriter(sw,
            (HTMLDocument) CurrentStorage.get().openNote(note), _charset,
            _num);
    try {
        writer.write();
        sw.flush();
        sw.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        new ExceptionDialog(ex);
    }
    text = sw.toString();
    if (_xhtml) {
        text = HTMLFileExport.convertToXHTML(text);
    }

    text = Pattern
            .compile("<body(.*?)>", java.util.regex.Pattern.DOTALL
                    + java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).split(text)[1];
    text = Pattern
            .compile("</body>", java.util.regex.Pattern.DOTALL
                    + java.util.regex.Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).split(text)[0];

    text = "<div class=\"note\">" + text + "</div>";

    if (_titlesAsHeaders) {
                    text = "\n\n<div class=\"date\">"
                + note.getDate().getFullDateString()
                + ":</div>\n<h1 class=\"title\">" + note.getTitle()
                + "</h1>\n" + text;
    }

    return text;
}


private static String generateNav(Note prev, Note next) {
    String s = "<hr></hr><div class=\"navigation\"><table border=\"0\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"2\"><tr><td width=\"33%\">";
    if (prev != null)  {  
        s += "<div class=\"navitem\"><a href=\"" + prev.getId() + ".html\">"
                + Local.getString("Previous") + "</a><br></br>"
                + prev.getDate().getMediumDateString() + " "
                + prev.getTitle() + "</div>";
    }

    else {
        s += "&nbsp;";
            s += "</td><td width=\"34%\" align=\"center\"><a href=\""
            + output.getName()
            + "\">Up</a></td><td width=\"33%\" align=\"right\">";
    }

    if (next != null) {
        s += "<div class=\"navitem\"><a href=\"" + next.getId() + ".html\">"
                + Local.getString("Next") + "</a><br></br>"
                + next.getDate().getMediumDateString() + " "
                + next.getTitle() + "</div>";
    }

    else {
        s += "&nbsp;";
    }
    s += "</td></tr></table></div>\n";
    return s;
}



private static void generateChunks(Writer w, Vector notes) {
    Object[] n = notes.toArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        Note note = (Note) n[i];
        CalendarDate d = note.getDate();
        if (_chunked) {
            File f = new File(output.getParentFile().getPath() + "/"
                    + note.getId()
                    + ".html");
            Writer fw = null;
            try {
                if (_charset != null) {
                    fw = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(f),
                            _charset);
                }

                else {
                    fw = new FileWriter(f);
                }

                String s = "<html>\n<head>\n"+charsetString+"<title>" + note.getTitle()
                        + "</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n" + getNoteHTML(note);

                if (_navigation) {
                    Note nprev = null;
                    if (i > 0) {
                        nprev = (Note) n[i - 1];
                    }

                    Note nnext = null;
                    if (i < n.length - 1) {
                        nnext = (Note) n[i + 1];
                    }

                    s += generateNav(nprev, nnext);
                }
                s += "\n</body>\n</html>";
                fw.write(s);
                fw.flush();
                fw.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                new ExceptionDialog(ex, "Failed to write to " + output, "");
            }
        }
        else {
            write(w, "<a name=\""  + "\">" + note.getDate() +"</a>\n" + getNoteHTML(note) + "</a>\n");
        }
    }
}


private static void write(Writer w, String s) {
    try {
        w.write(s);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        new ExceptionDialog(ex, "Failed to write to " + output, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? The first thing I would do with this code would be to get most all of that program logic code **out** of your GUI and into it's own control and model classes, and unit test those. You want to strive for code that has high cohesion and low coupling, with small independently testable classes. There's no reason to try to do unit testing with that combined logic/gui code.

Comment: I am honestly completely lost. I have a class that creates and HTML with certain aspect that I want to put into a report. I wasn't sure if it was worth testing the code above or not. I am going to post the class that converts everything to HTML for a report. I think that testing that code might be better. The main question I have is how to get started to Unit test the code. I have tried simple things, but can not get anything to work correctly.

Answer (score 5):

As it has already been mentioned, basically you should move out the application logic from the GUI code.

Unit testing usually doesn't work like write working code then add tests to it. First you should think about

- what is the testable part of the logic and what isn't
- how will you separate them
- how will you test the testable part

Directly testing GUI code usually does not work (except with some rare and well-designed UI frameworks), since your test would have to deal with a lot of technical problems (like framework initialization, instantiation of UI objects, triggering events properly, etc). So you should create a more abstract layer of the app. In a bigger picture, it will lead to the well-known Model-View-Controller pattern (de-facto standard design pattern for user interfaces since Smalltalk), where the model layer is independent from the UI framework, therefore it is simply testable.

So as some kind of case study, lets walk through the above concepts:

First lets check what is testable, what isn't and what stops you from writing tests:

> chooser.setDialogTitle(Local.getString("Export Project Report"));

This single line deals with both rendering and i18n, not really a good idea. Furthermore, the use of static methods is a top blocker antipattern for writing tests.

> String lastSel = (String) Context.get("LAST_SELECTED_EXPORT_FILE");

Static method call here again, also it would be hard to determine the responsibility of that Context class.

> Local.getString("Export Project Report")

also a static call, kind of duplicate code too

...and so on (static calls everywhere). Now lets see what kind of more abstract model we can create for this. First lets start with
some textual description of the requirements:

- There is a title (used both in the JFileChooser and the ProjectExportDialog) to be internationalized by key "Export Project Report"
- there is a previously selected directory (lastSel) which value we take granted at the beginning
- the encoding (enc) is similar to enc, nullable value too
- the dialog location (positioning) contains some arithmetic, we should test it
- if the user selects a file, then we should store it as the last selected directory
- there is an opened (current) project too, which we will save at the end
- there is something you call "nument", I don't understand what it is, but it should be true if the user selects the 2nd entry from dlg.encCB

Untestable parts:

- chooser... calls: UI-specific configuration of the JFileChooser, also it doesn't contain any control structures or calculation, so we won't test it

Now we are going to design a testable model class. While doing it, we will keep two principles in mind:

- we are going to put as much logic into the model as we can
- we don't want to rewrite your entire app for this time. So instead of getting rid of all the static calls, we abstract them away as simply as possible.

So now lets create some sort of abstract model for this (summary after code):

```
public class ProjectExportModel {
  // see the reasoning below
  public static ProjectExportModel create() {
    return new ProjectExportModel(Local::getString,
        (String) Context.get("LAST_SELECTED_EXPORT_FILE"),
        Context::put);
  }

  private final Function<String, String> i18n;

  private final File lastSelectedExportFile;

  private final Consumer<File> lastSelectedFileSaver;

  private String encoding;

  private boolean nument;

  private boolean xhtml;

  public ProjectExportModel(final Function<String, String> i18n, final File lastSelectedExportFile,
      final Consumer<File> lastSelectedFileSaver) {
    this.i18n = i18n;
    this.lastSelectedExportFile = lastSelectedExportFile;
    this.lastSelectedFileSaver = lastSelectedFileSaver;
  }

  /**
   * Called after a file has been selected from the JFileChooser
   *
   * Things to test:
   * - lastSelectedFileSaver.accept(file.getPath()) should be called - you may use a
   * mocking library to test
   * - the xhtml flag should be changed - testing is easy
   *
   */
  public void fileSelected(final File file) {
    // TODO
  }

  /**
   * At this point we break a bit the concept of the UI-independent model layer, since Point and Dimension
   * are UI-framework-related classes. But these 2 classes are easy to instantiate and easy to assert on the
   * returned value, so good-enough solution this time.
   */
  public Point getDialogLocation(final Dimension frameSize, final Point frameLocation) {
    return null; // TODO implement the positioning
  }

  public String getFrameTitle() {
    // TODO test if it calls and returns i18n.get("Export Project Model") - you need mocking here too
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Two things to be tested here:
   * - if CurrentProject.save() is called
   * - if ReportExporter.export(...) is called with the right parameters
   *
   * You are quite stuck here, since static methods cannot be mocked. Instead it would be better to change your APIs to make
   * these instance methods, since in the current way it is untestable. After changing these to instance methods, you should add
   * 2 more parameters to the constructor: a Project instance and a ReportExporter instance.
   * You can use mockito or easymock for mocking.
   */
  public void save() {

  }

  /**
   * You may call it from the view layer after calling fileSelected().
   *
   * To be tested:
   * - the proper change of the encoding member
   * - the proper change of the nument member
   */
  public void selectedEncodingChanged(final int selectedIndex) {
    // TODO implemenent the change of encoding and nument member
  }

}
```

Summary:

- this class is easy to instantiate and test
- in the tests you will use its explicit constructor to create instances
- for "production" usage, you will have to create a View class, which handles the swing-related code, accepts a ProjectExportModel instance as its parameter, and calls it methods, so you wire the tested model into the untestable UI-related code, while keeping the latter one minimal. Also, in this case you will create the model instance with ProjectExportModel.create() , since that methods wires the further dependencies in a way that it will more or less nicely interact with the other static methods of your app. This is a good technique for extracting testable parts while you don't necessarily have to remove all static methods from the app, we have just separated them away.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for this answer and your efforts.

Comment: You're welcome. I forgot to mention that you will need some getters (getXhtml() and getNumen() and getEncoding()) to make those values accessible from your test, so you can assert on them

Comment: Actually I'm not the original poster, but rather the commenter to his post.